# Count value based on name and number

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm using the MS Excel 2016.

Can anyone help me to create the formula.

I want to count the **Total Approved** (of days) **D2:D9** based on the **Name** (company) **B2:B9** and **Approved** (days) **C2:C9** as I adding the **Name** and **Approved** in the future. Also when the **Approved** (days) value is **0 (zero-menaning the request is not approved)** it will return to the previous value of **Total Approved (days) as seen on C6 & D6.** I have tried several formula using COUNTIF, COUNTIFS and SUMIF but nothing work.

[image: picture of the ms excel]

Comment: Could you please add desired output too? Currently your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: I have upload a picture with all the outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `SUMIF` is the right function you need. I got result as shown in picture with function:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:B2; "=" & B2; $C$2:C2)
```

This is function for cell D2, then you can copy it by dragging down.
I hope that I understood your question right.

To explain it:

1. the first parameter `$B$2:B2` is range of values which will be compared by condition.
2. the second parameter `"=" & B2` is condition. It can be for example "> 16000" but we need to compare it by cell on current row so we concatenate comparing sign and the cell.
3. the third parameter `$C$2:C2` is range where to sum. It's an optional parameter and it is used when the first parameter doesn't point to summed values

The dollar locks cell pointer during copying.

Comment: MS Excel said there’s error on the formula

Answer (score 0):

The formula is

```
=IF(B2="","",SUMIFS(C$2:C2,B$2:B2,B2))
```

Thanks to JeteMC for the formula